# as3 code for a blinking light?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I am trying to make a game where people have to identify a lighthouse, and then drag a  symbol over to it. I have the drag and drop code fine, but I am wondering what is the best way to animate my lighthouse. I have a seperate movie clip called lightFlash that I am trying to time, and it will just sit beside the lighthouse. I am trying to use a timer to make it flash. What I want is it to wait 3 seconds, flash for a second, then wait 3 seconds etc. this is what I have so far, not a lot, so any help would be appreciated!

```
lightFlash.alpha=0;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void {
lightFlash.alpha=1;
//wait for one second
}
myTimer.start();
```

i can already see i would have a problem that i would be losing a second of the timer each time if i did it this way, there is probably a much better way I should be doing this, any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is, but looking at your code, I would suspect that it turns on after 3 seconds, then never turns off. Is that correct?

Comment: Hey, I am more just looking for suggestions as to what to do, yep only turns on, not sure how to code the turn off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var isOn:Boolean;

lightFlash.alpha=0;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void {
   isOn = !isOn;
   if (isOn) {
      lightFlash.alpha=1;

     //wait for one second
     myTimer.delay = 1000;
   } else {
      lightFlash.alpha = 0;
      myTimer.delay = 3000;
     //wait for three seconds
   }
}
```